# Android: What image format should I pass into Google Cloud Storage

Tags: java, android, image, google-cloud-platform, retrofit

I am working on an Android application and I am trying to consume an endpoint that takes in an image, saves it to *Google Cloud Storage* and returns a URL.

#### Question:

I'm NOT new to working with endpoints but **I don't know what image object to send** (A Uri, a bitmap, a file, etc). Every format I use returns an *Internal Server Error*.

Here's the part of my user service interface responsible for making the request:

```
@POST("/add")
Call<PhotoUrlGetter> getUrlForPhoto(@Body Uri media);
```

Here's the part of my code where I'm actually making the request:

```
Uri media = ""; //the value is gotten from the image the user selected from gallery

UserService photoService = ServiceGeneratorForMedia.createService(UserService.class, "photoservice");

    Call<PhotoUrlGetter> photoCall = photoService.getUrlForPhoto(media);

    photoCall.enqueue(new Callback<PhotoUrlGetter>() {
             @Override
             public void onResponse(Call<PhotoUrlGetter> call, Response<PhotoUrlGetter> response) {
                  if(response.isSuccessful()){
                     Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), response.body().getMediaUrl(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         }
                  else{
                         Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Integer.toString(response.code()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         }
                      }

              @Override
              public void onFailure(Call<PhotoUrlGetter> call, Throwable t) {
                       Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Kindly drop a comment if there's any code snippet that's required and that I omitted. I was trying not to make the question too long.

Comment: You may want to check if your server has read and write permissions enabled for your client

Comment: It does. I have consumed other endpoints in this same application.